# Manage Taskbar Align Windows 11 - Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, taskbar, windows-11

I want align the taskbar of windows 11 to the left side using PowerShell.

I did this:

```
New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "TaskbarAl" -Value "0" -PropertyType Dword
```

I review and the value was changed but the taskbar don't move.

Comment: Windows 11 taskbar is bottom only

Comment: @Anders based on the Reg Entry, I think they mean align the start menu to left as opposed to center on the taskbar.

Comment: That may be. Either way, just changing the registry is not enough, you would have to tell the shell with a broadcast message.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set the Start menu to align left with Powershell...

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\advanced -Name 'TaskbarAl' -Type 'DWord' -Value 0
```

This is how I changed the search bar to a icon...

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search -Name 'SearchboxTaskbarMode' -Type 'DWord' -Value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have been setting `HKLM`, not `HKCU`.

In a Terminal/CMD prompt:

```
# Query current value
reg query hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\advanced /v TaskbarAl

# Set left align
reg add hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\advanced /v TaskbarAl /t REG_DWORD /f /d 0

# Set center align
reg add hkcu\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\advanced /v TaskbarAl /t REG_DWORD /f /d 1
```

Nothing else is required; the changes take effect instantly.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why but with Powershell I could not did it. Finally I did with "reg add".

Comment: Did you add any more changes or just the single registry?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).